# Android Xamarin: not able to read from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences

I am getting the default text and not the actual text saved when trying to access a shared preference. I have tested that it returns true when saving so I am pretty sure the problem is in reading from the preference file.

The preference class

```
public class SaveWarningMessage : Activity
{
    private ISharedPreferences myPref;
    private ISharedPreferencesEditor myPrefEditor;
    private Context myContext;

    public void MyAppPref(Context context)
    {
        this.myContext = context;
        myPref = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(myContext);
        myPrefEditor = myPref.Edit();
    }

    public void SaveString(string text)
    {
        myPrefEditor.PutString("warning text", text);
        var returnValue = myPrefEditor.Commit();


    }

    public string GetString()
    {
        return myPref.GetString("warning text", "could not get pref");
    }
 }
}
```

The class saving the preference:

```
 string warningText = Intent.GetStringExtra("warningText");

        Context mContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
        SaveWarningMessage classInstans = new SaveWarningMessage();
        classInstans.MyAppPref(mContext);
        classInstans.SaveString(warningText);
```

The class reading from the preference:

```
        Context mContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
        SaveWarningMessage classInstans = new SaveWarningMessage();
        classInstans.MyAppPref(mContext);
        string message = classInstans.GetString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would not subclass it from `Activity`(?) and use the `.actor` to instance your `ISharedPreferences`, along with a few other changes you end up with this example.

Example:

```
public class SaveWarningMessage
{
    public const string WARNINGTEXT = "warning text";
    ISharedPreferences myPref;

    public SaveWarningMessage(Context context)
    {
        myPref = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public void SaveString(string text)
    {
        var myPrefEditor = myPref.Edit();
        myPrefEditor.PutString(WARNINGTEXT, text);
        if (!myPrefEditor.Commit())
        {
            Log.Error("SomeTag", $"Saving {text} to Pref:{WARNINGTEXT} failed");
        }
        // Or replace the Commit & check of return the following
        // if you do not care about checking the return value 
        // myPrefEditor.Apply();
    }

    public string GetString()
    {
        return myPref.GetString(WARNINGTEXT, "could not get pref");
    }
}
```

Then you can you it like this:

```
string warningText = "SomeStringToSave";
SaveWarningMessage classInstans = new SaveWarningMessage(Application.Context);
classInstans.SaveString(warningText);

SaveWarningMessage classInstans2 = new SaveWarningMessage(Application.Context);
string message = classInstans2.GetString();
Log.Debug("SO", message);
```

Comment: Your comments makes a lot of sense and I implemented the changes, however it still does not work, and I am even more confused now... But thx

Comment: @MajaOkholm So when you call `classInstans2.GetString();` you are getting `could not get pref` instead of `SomeStringToSave`?

Comment: @MajaOkholm said that usually I use a completely different approach too and that probably you did well changing your code, try what I wrote in my answer, I'm really curious to see if I nailed it.

Comment: @SushiHangover yes excatly, it tells me "could not get pref"

Comment: @MauroPiccotti I tried your approach too, both Apply() instead of Commit() and myContext.SharedPreferences but it didnt work eaither. I am wondering if the error can be somewhere else in my code... this think is giving me a headache

Comment: @MajaOkholm I'm always more curious, after I'll write you down something different. Meanwhile I deleted my answer.